# sendmmsg always returning 1

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm trying to work with `sendmmsg`.  My program works fine but `sendmmsg` is always sending 1 packet at a time (returns 1).  I've checked via `gdb` that `vlen` is set to the correct value (128) and, as I said, it does send the packet just fine.  Is there anything special I have to do to enable `sendmmsg` on a socket?  It is a datagram (UDP) socket if that makes a difference.  Also, this happens on both Ubuntu 16 and RHEL 7.2.

UPDATE: Also, in case it matters, I am running in non-blocking mode, so I am not surprised it returns less than 128, just that it always returns 1.

UPDATE: Added MCVE:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

const int SND_BUFFER_SIZE = 212992;
const int PORT = 3333;
const int NUM_MESSAGES = 128;
const int BYTES_PER_MESSAGE = 1024;

int numSendCalls = 0;
int numPacketsSent = 0;

void SetSndBufferSize(int socketFd) {
    int sndBufferSize = SND_BUFFER_SIZE;
    socklen_t sndBufferSizeLen = sizeof(int);

    // Set the value
    if(setsockopt(socketFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char*) &sndBufferSize, sndBufferSizeLen) != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not set the send buffer size (errno=" + std::string(strerror(errno)) + ")");
    }

    // Confirm the value was set as desired
    if(getsockopt(socketFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char*) &sndBufferSize, &sndBufferSizeLen) != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not fetch the send buffer size after setting it (errno=" + std::string(strerror(errno)) + ")");
    }

    if(sndBufferSize != (SND_BUFFER_SIZE * 2)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("The underlying OS could not set the send buffer size to what we wanted (" + std::to_string(SND_BUFFER_SIZE) + ") and instead it was (" + std::to_string(sndBufferSize / 2) + ")");
    }

}

struct sockaddr_in MakeAddress(std::string destinationAddress, uint16_t destinationPort) {
    struct sockaddr_in result;
    result.sin_family = AF_INET;
    result.sin_port = htons(destinationPort);
    if(inet_aton(destinationAddress.c_str(), &result.sin_addr) == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid IPv4 address " + destinationAddress);
    }
    return result;
}

void Connect(int socketFd) {
    auto addr = MakeAddress("127.0.0.1", 3333);
    if(connect(socketFd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to connect to address (" + std::string(strerror(errno)) + ")");
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> MakeDataBuffers() {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_MESSAGES; i++) {
        result.emplace_back(BYTES_PER_MESSAGE, 'W');
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector<struct iovec> MakeIovecs(std::vector<std::string> & dataBuffers) {
    std::vector<struct iovec> result;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_MESSAGES; i++) {
        result.emplace_back();
        result[i].iov_base = (void*) dataBuffers[i].data();
        result[i].iov_len = BYTES_PER_MESSAGE;
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector<struct mmsghdr> MakeHeaders(std::vector<struct iovec> & iovecs) {
    std::vector<struct mmsghdr> result;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_MESSAGES; i++) {
        result.emplace_back();
        result[i].msg_hdr.msg_name = NULL;
        result[i].msg_hdr.msg_namelen = 0;
        result[i].msg_hdr.msg_iov = (struct iovec*) &iovecs[i];
        result[i].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
        result[i].msg_hdr.msg_control = NULL;
        result[i].msg_hdr.msg_controllen = 0;
        result[i].msg_hdr.msg_flags = 0;
        result[i].msg_len = 0;
    }
    return result;
}

void Send(int socketFd, std::vector<struct mmsghdr> & msgvec) {
    struct mmsghdr * msgvecdata = (struct mmsghdr*) msgvec.data();
    unsigned int size = msgvec.size();
    int numUpdated = sendmmsg(socketFd, msgvecdata, size, 0);
    numSendCalls++;
    if(numUpdated < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error sending packets (" + std::string(strerror(errno)) + ")");
    }
    numPacketsSent += numUpdated;
}

void Reset(std::vector<struct mmsghdr> & msgvec) {
    for(auto it = msgvec.begin(); it < msgvec.end(); it++) {
        it->msg_len = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto socketFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
    SetSndBufferSize(socketFd);
    Connect(socketFd);
    auto dataBuffers = MakeDataBuffers();
    auto iovecs = MakeIovecs(dataBuffers);
    auto headers = MakeHeaders(iovecs);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Send(socketFd, headers);
        Reset(headers);
    }
    std::cout << "Sent: " << std::to_string(numPacketsSent) << " packets across " << std::to_string(numSendCalls) + " calls" << std::endl;
    close(socketFd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sendmmsg()` returns the number of elements of the vector that were updated, not the number of packets sent. The number of bytes sent per element is written in the vector itself. Check the documentation of `sendmmsg()` [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmmsg.2.html). In short, if you only sent one message, then you'll get a result of 1.

Comment: I sent 128 messages.  I checked and the bytes written was equal to the full length on the first packet and 0 on the rest.

Comment: It's kinda hard to debug code that you can't see.  You've been around SO long enough to know the drill — MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: I've added an MCVE.

Comment: the posted code is C++, not C.   Please remove the `c` tag and add the `c++` tag.  They are two very different languages

Comment: the function: `sendmmsg()` is not ever called in the posted code. so your question, including the posted code do not match.

Comment: sendmmsg is called in the 3rd line of the Send method.  I will add the c++ tag, it makes more sense now that I've posted my code.  I should also add that I've sense determined the method I am using vectors above is unsafe and was the cause of the RHEL bug so I do not suggest using it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it appears the problem was that no one was listening on the port and the ICMP unreachable responses were triggering the sendmmsg to return early.  If I open up a recipient with nc then everything works as expected, on Ubuntu at least.

I had thought this might be the case a while back and so had squelched ICMP on RHEL but I had a bug in my code that only exhibited itself on RHEL.

Comment: This is a great observation!!  It would be nice to be put in the man page for sendmmsg, it will save a lot of hairs.  Thank you Pace!